# show div after select in drop-down select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how to show div after selecting it in select in drop-down?

below is my code

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectoption').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '0'){
        $("#option0").show();
      }
      else  if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#option1").show();
      }
       else
      {
        $("#option2").show();
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#option0,
#option1,
#option2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-12">
    <select id="selectoption">
        <option value="0">Option 1</option>
        <option value="1">Option 2</option>
        <option value="2">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="option0">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="option1">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="option2">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code works, but I want the div to be hidden if another one was selected + the code to be scalable - i.e. without 10 else when there are 10 divs

Comment: FYI the now-deleted answer combining with `data-option` *is* the better solution as it doesn't rely on incrementing IDs which are more hassle than they're worth (I mean, `$("[id^=..` is just nasty (IMO)) and, I believe, incrementing IDs are an anti-pattern (though I don't have an evidence link)

Comment: @Sfili_81 there may be "no need" to add data- but it's still a better option.  You should undelete your answer as it's the only *sensible* solution provided.

Answer (score 1):

First of all hide your div using wild card and show `div` based upon dropdown value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectoption').on('change', function() {
    $("[id^='option']").hide();
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#option" + val).show();

  });
});
```

```css
#option0,
#option1,
#option2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-12">
  <select id="selectoption">
    <option value="0">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    <option value="2">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div id="option0">
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4">
    <div id="option1">
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4">
    <div id="option2">
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add common class to all the div, so that on each click you can hide it by classname. Then get value of selected item, and based on values select item and show it.

```
$('#selectoption').on('change', function() {

    var getValue = $(this).val();

    $(".common").hide();
    $("#option" + getValue).show();

});
```

---

**Html Markup:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div  class="common" id="option0">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="common" id="option1">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="common"  id="option2">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While your answer might fix the problem the OP is facing, "Code only" answer are in general a bad idea because it leave no explanation about what was wrong or why your code will fix the problem. Remember giving answer is about education others.

Comment: Add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not optimal, but all you have to do is hide everything before showing a new one.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#option0").show();
    $('#selectoption').on('change', function() {
    $("#option0").hide();
    $("#option1").hide();
    $("#option2").hide();

      if ( this.value == '0'){
        $("#option0").show();
      }
      else  if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#option1").show();
      }
       else
      {
        $("#option2").show();
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#option0,
#option1,
#option2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-12">
    <select id="selectoption">
        <option value="0">Option 1</option>
        <option value="1">Option 2</option>
        <option value="2">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="option0">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="option1">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="option2">
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum... Example...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```